# AG Grid serverside minifilter filtering

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using AG Grid with viewport rowModel, I have large datasets. When using a Set Filter I populate the set data from server, but datasets are very large so I populate a small subset then wait for user to filter this down with minifilter. When user types into minifilter input, I want to re-request data from server. I don't see any provision in the API to know when user types into the MiniFilter input - am I missing something or is this not possible ?

Answer (score 0):

there is no AG Grid API method for that, but you could get hold of the MiniFilter input quite easily, see the `onFilterOpened` prop and type anything in the 'Athlete` MiniFilter.
https://plnkr.co/edit/Y3YzkEePVyHZ1I9w?open=index.tsx